# Watin accessing localhost

Tags: mstest, watin, iis-express

When executing the c# code in MSTest involving WatiN

```
var browser = new IE("http://localhost:56034/");
```

The web page is displayed in IE but after about a minute, I receive the error

Timeout while waiting for main document becoming available with the error message

**Timeout while waiting for main document becoming available**

The code

```
var browser = new IE("http://www.bing.com/");
```

works fine.

I am running IIS Express 7.5. Since I am new to the WatiN I am hoping that I am missing something simple.

Comment: http://localhost:56034 works fine if VS2010 is "run as administrator.  This is executing in VS2010 sp1 win 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice in http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/15/watin-and-com-errors-enable-ie-protected-mode-for-local-intranet-zone, turning **ON** protected mode for the intranet zone in IE 8 solved the problem.